PDO Firebird 2.5 and PHP 7.3 : unable to use temporary table
I'm populating a temporary table with items, and then use this table to filter with a SQL JOIN operator, but it does not work.
Snippet below show the problem.
$pdo->beginTransaction(); 
$pdo->->exec("INSERT INTO LISTEREF2 (DATA) VALUES ('foo1');"); 
$sth = $pdo->query('SELECT r.* FROM LISTEREF2 r'); 
if ($sth) {     
  $rowTable = $sth->fetchAll(); 
  logIt('fetchAll '.print_r($rowTable,true)); 
}

Populating is OK (rowCount=1), but the 'select' on this table is empty as if the connection is different.

I have found a solution to my problem.
By replacing:
$pdo->beginTransaction();

with:
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
$pdo->exec("SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED NO WAIT");


Your solution implies that the table has attribute "on commit delete rows" which you forgot to mention. With table "on commit preserve rows" the problem wouldn't happen.

@user13964273 However, I would expect explicitly starting a transaction like the OP did to execute all operations in a single transaction.

@MarkRotteveel Indeed, beginTransaction() is explicitly documented to turn autocommit mode off. It means that something else must be wrong. OP didn't check returned value, may be an error happen on the call.
